# Facebook Like button not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I am using the XFBML version of the Like button because I need the Send button.

Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=178223665570391345&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>
```

I use  so that it will Like the page it shows up on.

The Send button <strike>works fine but</strike> the Like button does't work.  I've tried liking it a few times, I get this in the JS response:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":false,"error_info":null}}
```

You can see the page here: http://www.salemarked.com/share/152/

The Send button doesn't work either and here is the error it gives me - http://d.pr/VPO1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try removing the 'AddThis' code & buttons. Let me know if that makes a difference.

Comment: I got it to work now.  Removed current_url() since by default, href is going to be the current page if left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work now. Removed current_url() since by default, href is going to be the current page if left blank.